# Construct-in-place an unmoveable object in a map

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, stdatomic

I'm trying to construct an object in a map that contains an atomic, so it can neither be copied nor moved AFAICT.

My reading of C++ [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace) is that map `emplace` should be able to do this. But the following code does not compile because of deleted or non-existent constructors. Using `make_pair` does not help.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <unordered_map>

class Z {
  std::atomic<int> i;
};

std::unordered_map<int, Z> map;

void test(void) {
  map.emplace(0, Z()); // error
  map[0] = Z(); // error
}
```

Is this possible, and if not, why not?

EDIT: Compiler is gcc 4.8.1, on Linux

Comment: What compiler do you use?

Comment: `emplace` takes the constructor arguments, but you are passing a temporary object.

Comment: @NeilKirk Then how else would one invoke the no-arg constructor?

Comment: `map[0];` seems to work.

Comment: how about `std::unordered_map<int, std::shared_ptr<Z>> map;`?

Comment: @stas `unique_ptr` is a possibility; overhead of `shared_ptr` is a no-go.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::make_tuple(0), std::make_tuple())` will construct a zero-argument `Z` at location `0`.

`map[0]` will also do it if it is not already there.

`emplace` takes the arguments to construct a `std::pair<const K, V>`.  `std::pair` has a `std::piecewise_construct_t` tagged constructor that takes two tuples, the first is used to construct the first argument, the second to construct the second argument.

so `std::pair<const int, Z> test( std::piecewise_construct, std::make_tuple(0), std::make_tuple() )` constructs the `test`s elements in-place, the `const int` is constructed with `(0)`.  The `Z` is constructed with `()`.

`map.emplace` forwards is arguments to the `std::pair` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to use `operator[]` to construct the value inside the map. Then you can assign a value (or operate on it as needed).

Answer (score -1):

May be the following solution will be better, since atomic is not copyable:

```
class Z {
  std::atomic<int> i;
};

std::unordered_map<int, std::shared_ptr<Z>> map;

void test(void) {
  map.emplace(0, std::make_shared<Z>()); // OK
}
```

Comment: The overhead of `shared_ptr` is non-trivial.