# How can you emplace directly a mapped value into an unordered_map?

Tags: c++, std

Have I understood it correctly that the ::insert function for std::unordered_map takes a std::pair<'key', 'mapped_value'> and emplace simply takes:

```
first_arg is the key

second_arg is the mapped element
```

so:

```
#include <unordered_map>

struct SomeStruct
{
    SomeStruct(int, double, char) {};
};
int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int, SomeStruct> mymap2;
    mymap2.emplace(6, SomeStruct{ 5, 0.0, 'c' });
}
```

This means that there's no such thing as building my mapped value (struct) in place, is there? If these are the arguments that 'emplace' takes then why does it have variadic arguments in the first place? With variadic arguments the first argument could have been the key and the remaining arguments could have been the constructor arguments for the class type to construct in place, perfectly forwarded, that would have been more efficient, and if I'm right then in this case emplace is not that different from 'insert', which would do a copy or move. However in the above example 'emplace' looks to be doing a copy or move construction anyway.

Have I understood these arguments correctly? If I'm right then it's strange that there would be variadic template arguments.

Edit: I checked in my program above the constructor for SomeStruct is called when creating the temporary and then the move constructor, I assume to move it into the bucket. Is there any way to build it in place the std::vector::emplace does?

Comment: I believe you need `std::piecewise_construct` for that: `mymap2.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(6), std::forward_as_tuple(5, 0.0, 'c'));`

Comment: See constructors of `std::pair` on cppreference, one of them is a piece-wise constructor. This one constructing the struct inplace. This is useful for constructing non-movable/copyable classes in maps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Construct-in-place an unmoveable object in a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33423023/construct-in-place-an-unmoveable-object-in-a-map)

Answer (score 2):

`emplace` is variadic to deal with all overloads of the [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) offered by `std::pair`. In particular `std::pair` has a piecewise constructor. It takes a `std::piecewise_construct_t` as first paramter. It allows to forward paramters to the constructor of the mapped value as a tuple.

The example from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace):

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <utility>
> #include <string>
> #include <unordered_map>
>  
> int main()
> {
>     std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> m;
>
>     // [...]
>  
>     // uses pair's template constructor
>     m.emplace("d", "ddd");
>  
>     // uses pair's piecewise constructor
>     m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
>               std::forward_as_tuple("c"),
>               std::forward_as_tuple(10, 'c'));
>     // as of C++17, m.try_emplace("c", 10, 'c'); can be used
>  
>     for (const auto &p : m) {
>         std::cout << p.first << " => " << p.second << '\n';
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: How is forwarding a tuple any better than forwarding the struct containing the same values?

Comment: @rubenvb i admit I dont understand it fully either, but note that `std::forward_as_tuple` returns a tuple of references

Comment: @rubenvb plus, consider the comment above: When the mapped value is neither copyable nor movable you can still piecewise construct it

Comment: There's a lot to take in here, but essentially the try_emplace takes the first argument as key, and any extra arguments as the constructor arguments? Then it won't construct a temporary and won't move it, it should construct it directly in place?

Comment: @Zebrafish as I understood it yes. The downside seems to be that "The element may be constructed even if there already is an element with the key in the container, in which case the newly constructed element will be destroyed immediately. "

Comment: @Zebrafish btw I was wondering the same recently. Why is there `emplace` when I have to construct the mapped value anyhow? `piecewise_construct` seems to be the answer, but this answer is only what I found out just now. I also have to read a bit more to fully understand it

Comment: In a tutorial I'm looking at try_emplace: "This new function proposed behaves similarly to emplace(), but has an advantage that is, it will not construct the object associated with the key, if the key already exists. This will boost the performance in case objects of that type are expensive to create." Just tried it, using emplace if the key already exists in the map it constructs the temporary but does not move it, it then destroys the temporary. Using try_emplace when a key already exists nothing is called. That's kinda cool, but I don't know how it works, I'll learn it some day I guess.